# Pattern matching with minus sign between spaces

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I have a variable `message` which I get from User input. For example:

> !word number
>   word-word---word

or

> !word
>   wordword-word

Currently I create a table and fill it with every single word/number (without digits like -)

```
--input table
it = {}
--put input in table
for _input in string.gmatch((message), '%w+') do
    it[#it+1] = { input=_input }
end
```

First of all I cant get words with minus between them to my table.
Also I cant check if `it[2].input` is not empty. This is an example how I check the table:

```
--TEST START
if it[1].input == 'test' then
    --do something
end
--TEST END
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619193/greed-non-greedy-pattern-matching-and-optional-suffixes-in-lua) without any working result.

Comment: Try `string.gmatch(message, '%S+')` to get words with dash inside.  Try `if (it[1] or {}).input == 'test' then` for checking values.

Comment: Awesome ... and that simple ... thank you very much!!!

Comment: Is `!word` a valid word, or `word`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- %s = space character
-- %- = escaped magic character
message = "!word number word-word---word"
-- might not be the most ideal method to fil an array up...
it = {(function() local t = {}; for _input in string.gmatch(message,"[^%s%-]+") do t[#t+1] = {input = _input} end return unpack(t) end)()}
print(t[2].input) --> number
--
--
it = {}
for _input in string.gmatch(message,"[^%s%-]+") do
    it[#it+1] = {input = _input}
end
-- now checking value should work fine
if (it[2] and it[2].input == "number") then -- checking that it[2] is set as something and then comparing input
   print("t[2].input = \"number\"");
end
```